# Amazon Linux AMI Test Page appears every time

Tags: html, linux, apache, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have a EC2 with apache2 and static web site in /var/www/html.
I changed one html file there and after that I can't access my web page with url - Amazon Linux AMI Test Page opens. 
After `sudo service apache2 restart`it becomes to work normally, but switched to the Amazon Linux AMI Test Page after some minutes.
I changed owner for html folder to user `sudo chown ubuntu /html` and it became works normally again, but every time I exit from ssh session it immediately starts to display Amazon test page.
I checked apache2 Document root in .conf and +r rights for files in html folder, they are normal. Why this issue happens?

Sometimes all pages working normally, but index.html returns 404 error

Comment: It means you don't have an index page. Place an `index.php` or `index.html` file there.

Comment: I checked it and it's in the right place. Sometimes it appears after refresh

Comment: Is that your browser that caching the Test Page? Try using a different browser.

Comment: It works normally before this issue appears

Comment: If you wouldn't mind, you can provide the URL here for us to see what exactly is happening.

Comment: ok - http://www.betaarmy.com/ thanks

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/64543/discussion-between-user1835337-and-kums).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like there are two elastic IPs assigned for the site. One of them is not working, while the other one works. EC2 is randomly picking one of the IPs (I found this after doing a wget request)

You will have to remove the one IP that is not related to your site.